# how to render <script> tag on GatsbyJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby, strapi

I have a strapi and gatsby project. Strapi editor is markdown, so I get a string with markdown content.

the blog post created on strapi some of them includes charts that have  and .

Using markdown to jsx won't render any of the codes that look like that. it's just white space.

Example code below:

````
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>```

What should I do?
````

Answer (score 0):

Make a component out of it and inject it into markdown using AST or MDX